# Get in Angular 4 data from Twitter

Tags: angular, twitter

i need advice. How can i get tweets with specific hashtags using Angular 4? I know that in Angular JS there is wrapper for Twitter API. What about Angular 4?

Answer (score -2):

There are many NPM packages that can help facilitate the data. Quite a few to choose from, https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/twitter.  I've used both Twitter and Twit with success.  Using their library makes it quite simple to achieve your query.